# new email send to Outlook.com never deliver but reply on Outlook.com email does

Tags: email, smtp, ptr-record

I dont know where i could start. There is the probleme.

If someone send me an email from Outlook.com, i received the email. If i reply, he will received my email.

If i write a new email and send it to the same addresse, the email will never arrived.

I check my server reputation, and everything is fine ..

My spf is good, my ptr is good ...

Any idea what i should check ?

Comment: When someone put a negative score, it's essential to explain why ...

Answer (score 1):

Since replaying to received email and sending a new one are the same things in tech terms (only difference are some SMTP headers in sent email) there is only one option left, as far as I see it: low reputation at Microsoft email infrastructure.

Microsoft is *probably* not trusting your emails and makes difference between "new" and response email (which contains important `In-Reply-To:` header with ID of mail sent from their side)

This lack of trust would be nothing new or unusual - in order to send email to them you have to establish positive reputation, which is long-term job. I suggest you to register your server's IP address to Smart Network Data Services and observe data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already sign to this "microsoft service" ... so i understand that is time that will "repair" my problem ?

Comment: I guess so, since reputation is never instantly established. BTW, throttling/rate limiting emails to Microsoft destinations would most certainly help. If you are running `Postfix` (you didn't tell us anything about OS/software) you may find out more [here](http://steam.io/2013/04/01/postfix-rate-limiting/).